# How to delete labels Python

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is that I want a tracker that tracker how many times a sentence has been sent and whenever I run :

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

root = Tk()
messages = 0
root.geometry('500x1400')

def startn():
    global messages
    global label
    message = "Read the Channel"
    spam = int(input('How many sentences will you send?'))
    for num in range(0, int((spam))):
        messages = int(messages + 1)
        label = Label(root, text= messages)
        label.pack()
    root.mainloop()


            
            
    
    
startn()
```

And whenever I add .destroy after the label.pack() it doesn't display anything (btw spam = 5)

[Output with .destroy after label.pack()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nLvR.png)
[Output without .destroy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0fHF.png)

Comment: if you are using `label.pack().destroy()` it is incorrect you have to use it in two different lines like `label.pack()` and `label.destroy()` and in your screenshot the labels already destroyed too, whats the matter?

Comment: You created it, used `pack` manager to put it on the window.If you add `.destroy` will destroy those label widgets, it surely display nothing.Your title is: *"How to delete labels Python"*, but you've got it.What do you want to do?

Comment: Oh, sorry I gave the general issue revolving the problem I had. I am so sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should do what you want. There is no need to destroy the label you should just reconfigure the same label with .configure() method. I suspect the method you really want is .pack_forget() so I did include that as well. I didn't run this code so if you have any issues please leave a comment so I can correct.

```py
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

root = Tk()
messages = 0
label = Label(root) # create your widgets early
root.geometry('500x1400')

def startn():
    global messages
    global label
    message = "Read the Channel"
    spam = int(input('How many sentences will you send?'))
    label.pack() # only need to pack it once
    for num in range(0, int((spam))):
        messages = int(messages + 1)
        label.configure(text= messages) # you should configure instead of making new label

def stopn():
    label.pack_forget() # the label reference still exists, but it is no longer packed. You can destroy the label, but I just leave it for the garbage collector.
    
startn()

root.after(10000, stopn) # will run stopn callback after 10 seconds
root.mainloop() # in my opinion should always be at the end.
```

Comment: What the point of the for loop because you could only see the last update by `label.configure(...)`?  Just call `label.configure(root, text=spam)` instead of the for loop having the same result.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    startn()
  File "C:\Users\chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\test2.py", line 18, in startn
    label.configure(root, text= messages)`

Sorry if the formatting is sloppy. @ShayneLoyd

Comment: @Chippery7 I corrected the issue. The .configure() method isn't supposed to have root passed to it. That was a mistake I made editing the code.